# Bing maps, to display a dot + zoom into the location of the user, windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a map in my app, but when it loads the zoom level is quite far out of where my location is.

So how does one make the map zoom into the excat location of the device and to display the dot, just like if one was to use the bing maps built in.

```
public location()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    map1.ZoomBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;          
}

private GeoCoordinateWatcher loc = null;

private void map1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loc = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
    //EventHandler for location service status changes
    loc.StatusChanged += loc_StatusChanged;
    //If the location service is disabled or not supported
    if (loc.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Disabled)
    {
        //Display a message
        MessageBox.Show("Location services must be enabled");
        return;
    }
    loc.Start();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loc = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
    //EventHandler for location service status changes
    loc.StatusChanged += loc_StatusChanged;
    //If the location service is disabled or not supported
    if (loc.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Disabled)
    {
        //Display a message
        MessageBox.Show("Location services must be enabled");
        return;
    }

    loc.Start();
}

void loc_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
    {
        map1.SetView(loc.Position.Location, 10.0);
        loc.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you altered the ZoomLevel in your SetView method? Try 17 rather than 10.

Comment: Thanks.How would one create a dot of some sort to show the excat location?

Comment: You could create a pushpin : http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/forums/windows-phone-development/PushPin-Loaction-change-in-Bing-Map